# WebView - Fill a form

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2013, windows-8

I'm developing a windows 8 app, and I need help.
It's possible fill a form, which is inside a webview with data of my application?

I will fill a form in my app. This data it should be sent to webview form.

```
<WebView Name="webView1" Source="https://www.nfp.fazenda.sp.gov.br/login.aspx" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="374" Margin="10,384,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="1346"/>
    <TextBox Name="login" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="515,218,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="39" Width="348"/>
    <Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="645,296,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="Button_Click"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes! It is possible with DOM manipulation of the page. To do DOM manipulation

```
string[] args = { "document.getElementById(\"myfield\").value =
 \"My default value\"" };
string foo = webView.InvokeScript("eval", args);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But how I choose which webview "input" fill?  I updated my code.

Comment: Find the id of the element you want to fill. If it has no id do like this formName.elements["element_name"].value = "My Default Value"